# Reading twitter feed

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

Previously I was using

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=xyz&count=5
```

to read the twitter feeds. 
But after the arrival of twitter api 1.1, I am getting Bad Authentication data error.
Am I missing something to be done?

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: **WHAT LANGUAGE ARE YOU USING**

Comment: I am using .NET. C#.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading feed, you have to authenticate first using token and key in dev.twitter.com site.

Also, you can try TweetSharp library. https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp.

**Update 19/10/2016:**
The Github  danielcrenna/TweetSharp is not available any more.
From https://github.com/shugonta/TweetSharp

> this project is officially archived / dead....
>   If you need commercial
>   and/or active support for a Twitter-based API wrapper, you may want to
>   orient your organization towards alternatives like [Twitterizer](http://twitterizer.net/) or 
>   [LINQ to Twitter](https://github.com/JoeMayo/LinqToTwitter).

However Nuget package [TweetSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp/)  is still available (Last updated 2013-06-22)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to do it with token and key.

Comment: Thanks, I used Tweetsharp and it works, but I want json as result. Would it be possible to get json with tweetsharp? Do you know any such method?

Comment: Well, You can use json.net library to convert to jSon object. The one I would recommend is Newtonsoft.Json library.

Comment: Yes I've done using that only. What i was looking for is a method of tweetsharp which returns json data.But I checked there is no such method available. Anyway, I've done it using Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you do it with [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/). Use a [StatusType.User](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Querying%20the%20User%20Timeline&referringTitle=Making%20Status%20Queries%20and%20Calls) query, like this:

```
        var statusTweets =
            (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
             where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                   tweet.ScreenName == "xyz" &&
                   tweet.IncludeEntities == true &&
                   tweet.IncludeRetweets == true &&
                   tweet.Count == 5
             select tweet)
            .ToList();

        var jsonData = twitterCtx.RawResult;
```

The RawResult property of the TwitterContext instance contains the JSON data that Twitter returns. So, you have a choice of using the deserialized tweets or the raw data that Twitter returns.