# Twitter API 1.1 to display latest tweets

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I was using the following code to get latest tweets of my account to my wordpress website. As soon as twitter launched its new API 1.1, it all broke completely. How to proceed.

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php' );
// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed( 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name='.$cvt_twitter );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly

    // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
    $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity( 5 ); 

    // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
    $rss_items = $rss->get_items( 0, $maxitems );

endif;
?>

<ul style="list-style:none;">
    <?php if ( $maxitems == 0 ) : ?>
        <li><?php _e( 'No items', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink. 
            foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
            <li>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                <a class="thumb" href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>" target="_blank">
                  <img width="100" height="auto" src="<?=$cvt_logo?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>"
                    title="<?php printf( __( 'Posted %s', 'my-text-domain' ), $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a') ); ?>" target="_blank">
                    <?php $string = esc_html( $item->get_title() );
                    $word = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ':')+1);
                    echo str_replace($word, "", $string); ?>
                </a>
            </div></div>            
        </li>
        <?php endforeach;
        endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to authenticate using token and secret key in-order to read the feed,  https://dev.twitter.com, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206726/reading-twitter-feed/17206811#17206811

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **[Twitter API 1.1 Client for WordPress](https://github.com/micc83/Twitter-API-1.1-Client-for-Wordpress)**.

It's very easy to implement and all you need is your **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret**.

Example (from the README):

```
<?php

// Include Twitter API Client
require_once( 'class-wp-twitter-api.php' );

// Set your personal data retrieved at https://dev.twitter.com/apps
$credentials = array(
  'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
);

// Let's instantiate Wp_Twitter_Api with your credentials
$twitter_api = new Wp_Twitter_Api( $credentials );

// Example a - Retrieve last 5 tweets from my timeline (default type statuses/user_timeline)
$query = 'count=5&include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=micc1983';
var_dump( $twitter_api->query( $query ) );
```